# Setup:static-content:deploy issue with locale

Tags: magento2, locale, static-content-deploy

I have enabled **Production mode**, and when I run  `setup:static-content:deploy`, it creates two folders - `en_AU` and `en_US`.

In `pub/static/frontend/mytheme/`, `en_US` folder has all nessesary files generated, and `en_AU` folder has only one `.js` file generated.

When I refresh my front-end, I can see all files including css and js are loaded from `en_AU` folder, but since this folder is emtpy, so my front-end is not displaying correctly. Then I need to manually copy everything from `en_US` to `en_AU` to make front-end working.

Why does system creates two folders with one has all contents, and another empty, but front-end is reading from the empty folder.

How can I fixed this issue ?

Comment: you can also add a locale variable with the static-content command, e.g.  'php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_AU' maybe that will solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've selected **English (United States)** in your locale settings: `Stores > Configuration > General > Locale Options`

`setup:static-content:deploy` by default deploys **en_US**

If you'd like to use **en_AU**, change your Locale Settings in the admin to **English (Australia)** and run `setup:static-content:deploy en_AU`

Comment: Very nice you mentioned static-content by default deploys en_US. I was wondering where did this en_US folder comes from.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to set the right language for your website `admin > Stores > Configuration > Locale`, if you inspect the dropdown options, you will see all the `code_ISO` and the `language name`, according to your post you will select :

   `English (Australia)` :: `<option value="en_AU">anglais (Australie)</option>`
2. You have to clean the content folder of : `pub/static`, `var/view_preprocessed`, `var/cache`
3. Now deploy the static-content, you can target only the locale language like this:

   - `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU`

**Bonus:** You can also deploy the static-content for the current theme only like this:

- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Theme/name en_AU`

Answer (score -2):

You don't have configured properly nginx or you remove .htaccess from `pub/static`. It need to have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This code ensure that files in `pub/static` are generated properly.

If there isn't even symlink then you get broken frontend.
Make sure to do properly deploy as mentioned above and of course check if write permission are correctly set (same as process php running magento)